# Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined

Tags: json, react-native, fetch

My code is working like it should, however I keep getting the error with the same name of this question's title on my mobile device whenever this function is called.

```
  _matchAddresses(id) {
   fetch('https://myapp.com/rest/jobs/address/' + id)
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then((responseJson) => {
     var addresses = [];
     console.log('addresses: ' + responseJson);
     for (var i=0; i<responseJson.length; i++) {
       addresses.push(responseJson[i]);
       for (var j=0; j<addresses.length; j++) {
         fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+ addresses[j].split(" ") + '&key=googleapikey')
         .then((response) => response.json())
         .then((responseJson) => {
           let lat = responseJson.results["0"].geometry.location.lat; //error here
           let lng = responseJson.results["0"].geometry.location.lng; //error here
           console.log("coordinates: " + lat + " " + lng); //returns coordinates every time

           if (this._latMatch(userLat, lat) && this._lngMatch(userLng, lng)) {
               this._myFunction();
               console.log("fire");
           }

         })
         .catch((error) => {
           console.error(error);
         });
     }
   }
 });
}
```

I know that lat and lng have been defined with some logging, so I dont't understand why I would still be getting the error. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `results["0"]` is coming back empty, which is why you are getting that error. Since you are iterating on a for loop and you are successfully printing out coordinates, my guess is that at least one of those fetches to Google's API is not returning the expected result. To test this you could log the results object before trying to access it and check the object returned before the error.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It turns out that one of the addresses on my back end had a typo in it, which was causing the googlemaps api to search for a non existent address. It is funny how I was getting the correct amount of different coordinates though... If I had enough reputation I would give you an up vote.

Comment: Glad I could help!